# PHP syntax: same snippets in same file return different values

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, echo

I'm having a hard time with PHP formatting. :P
In a function I have these strings and `$cache1` path is output properly (wordpress absolute upload path + `/json/dailymile/BLABLA.json`

```
$url1 = "http://api.dailymile.com/people/XXXXX/entries.json";
$cache1 = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/json/dailymile/'.sha1($url1).'.json';
```

Then I have a SIMILAR (if not the same) case but only God knows why, $cache2 returns just `/json/instagram/BLABLA.json` without wordpress upload path before.

```
$url2 = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$user_id.'/media/recent/?access_token='.$token.'&count='.$count;
$cache2 = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/json/instagram/'.sha1($url2).'.json';
```

These two snippets are in the same file and the top of this file I have `<?php $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); ?>`.

Why the second snippet doesn't return the WP upload dir before `/json/instagram/BLABLA.json` ?

Comment: We might need to see a bit more code. :)

Comment: Try inserting `var_dump($upload_dir);` right before the second snippet starts.

Comment: @ninetwozero added the whole function.

ComFreek: ok, trying right now

Comment: @ComFreek This is the output: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=9PmCQq9d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$upload_dir` is outside of the scope when using your code within a function. Using the `global` keyword you can import the variable from the global scope into the current one. Like this:

```
<?php
function get_instagram(...) {
    global $upload_dir;
    ...
}
```

Comment: While this works, one should rather pass `$upload_dir` as a parameter.

Comment: It depends on the use case and the quality of code you want to achieve. In this case it looks like a "quick hack", we have a function with plenty parameters already. You would probably first want to get rid of all the parameters by wrapping it in a class before you add yet another parameter.

Comment: But why I have other functions in the same file and instead for them it works also if it's not inside the function..?

Comment: Maybe in the other functions `$upload_dir` is defined before being used?